# Keep NSURLConnection open + Chunked Encoding Upload

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, chunked-encoding

I want keep a `NSURLConnection` open, and upload data via chunked transfer encoding. I have a buffer that reads in data, and as soon as I read in the data, I want to upload this data. I won't know how much data will be read ahead of time, so I need to keep the connection open.

From what I've seen on Stackoverflow, I've seen recommendations such as `setHTTPBodyStream`, `ASIHTTPRequest`, etc. However, I believe all of those does not allow me to add more data to the connection once it's opened.

Is there any way to do this in iOS? Any recommendation is welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you need NSInputStream and NSOutputStream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not actually try this myself, but have a look at "PostController.m" in the
[SimpleURLConnections](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleURLConnections/Introduction/Intro.html) sample project from the Apple Developer Library.

It shows how to create a socket pair where the reading end (`consumerStream` in the sample code) is used as `HTTPBodyStream` for the URL request, and you can write your data to the writing end (`producerStream`).

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising. I will look into it.